# Notepad++ - Binary text error

Tags: sorting, notepad++, binary-data

I have a huge txt file made using python. When I'm trying to sort it using Notepad++/TextFX it returns error: `This tool is not compatible with binary text. Please select text without [NUL] characters.`. Does it means that I have non-printable chars in this txt file? Is it possible to convert this file to compatible format so I could sort it using TextFX?

EDIT: I used mode 'a' in Python to write this file.

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

using TextFX in Notepad++ you could try the following:

1. Mark the suspicious part or the whole text
2. Select TextFX, TextFX Characters, Zap all nonprintable characters to #. (The last entry in that submenu.)

All the problematic characters should have been replaced with "#", you can then search for "#".

Another idea is the function: Search, "Find characters in range". Check "My range:" and enter "0" and "0" as range, to find [Nul] characters.

Lars